# What's the difference between the client and the server API

Tags: qt, pusher

I want to implement a Pusher client in Qt, and I was wondering what the difference is between the client API and the server API.
As they are telling on their [site](http://pusher.com/docs/libraries), clients are consumers and servers are producers (including authentication verifications).
Is it correct that a client cannot publish events, and that we always need a server to handle event distribution and authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct that a client cannot publish events, and that we always need a server to handle event distribution and authentication?

Clients can publish events, but only on authenticated channels: http://pusher.com/docs/client_events

Server libraries tend to have the functionality you mention. But it is possible to have all functionality in a single library. However, this way of dividing functionality fits well with enforcing security good practice and generally with where apps want to use it.

The iOS library (libPusher) provides more than the standard client functionality e.g. you can make calls to Pusher's web API.